# heat map using google maps javascript api not displayed in my pdf usign "wkhtmltopdf".I tried giving window_status on "tilesloaded" event

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

```
<div id="map">
</div>

<script>
    var map, heatmap;
    var heatpoints = [];

    function initMap(){

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/show_heat_map',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {},
            success: function(data, status, xhr){

                $.each(data["locations"], function(index, item){
                    if (index == 0) { //To get the center point of heat map
                        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                        zoom: 10,
                        center: {
                            lat: item["latitude"],
                            lng: item["longitude"]
                        }, 
                        mapTypeId: 'roadmap' //roadmap, satellite, hybrid, terrain
                    }); 
                    }
                    var lat = item["latitude"];
                    var lng = item["longitude"];
                    if (lat != null && lng != null) {
                        heatpoints.push(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng)); //all the heatpoints
                    }
                });
                console.log("HEAT POINTS IS "+heatpoints);
                heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
                    data: heatpoints,
                    map: map
                });
            },
            error: function(error){
                console.log("Error");
            }
        });


    }

</script>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key='+Rails.application.secrets.google_maps_api_key+'&libraries=visualization&callback=initMap' %>
```

The initMap gets called when the pdf is rendered. But it doesnt reach the map loading. If this doesnt work, is there a way i can do the same using any other gem like prawn. I felt wkhtmltopdf is very simple.

Comment: I don't see anywhere in this code where you are setting `window.status = 'tilesloaded'`. I would expect that to happen at the bottom of your `success` callback.

Comment: i did that inside the initmap function like -google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'tilesloaded', function(){
     window.status = 'done_with_heatmap';
   });

Comment: @Unixmonkey - is it actually possible for wkhtmltopdf to display map content? Because i saw that it doesn't support now.

Comment: I know that there are a lot of map libraries that it has trouble with, but I have heard that some (likely older versions) work. This is likely because `wkhtmltopdf` uses what is equivalent to a very old Chrome version, which doesn't support a lot of newer CSS and JS features.

Comment: thanks for the reply. @Unixmonkey. Do you have any experience using gem "grover"?

Comment: Never heard of it before. Looks cool.

Comment: @Unixmonkey - can u help me out on this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60747083/schmooze-process-failed-when-using-grover-gem-to-convert-html2pdf